# Daily agenda notification in calendar?

Tags: macos, calendar

I want to receive notification every morning with list of things (daily agenda) for the day in my Macbook. I could not find a way to set that up in Calendar, so is there another option or can I use AppleScript to accomplish this?

Comment: Calendar doesn't support this, but it should be possible to script something like that using AppleScript or similar. Are you open for such a solution?

Comment: @patrix, yes if it works I am open to the solution but I do not know how to do this in AppleScript.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but have a look at the "Today" view of the macOS [Notification Center](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21853).

[image]

Personally, I use the calendar in [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/). 
[image]

You find further calendar options in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/129731/45492).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple actually. Create a text document and name it daily agenda or whatever. Add your daily agenda items into that new text document.

1. Open calendar app and create a new event and name it "daily agenda"
   or whatever

[image]

2. Then on the right side of the calendar app click where you see the
   information and other items of that event

[image]

3. Edit the starts and ends times to what you would like them To be
4. Then click "repeats" and edit those values
5. Then click "alerts" and choose custom and select "Open file at time
   of event" and select that new text document you created with your
   itemized daily agenda items
6. Add multiple alerts if you would like

[image]

Now every time that calendar event runs, it will launch your daily agenda text document and any other alerts you have set up

Comment: hey, but i want the daily agenda to be the events of that specific day as a summary of things that are up ahead that day. I do not think this method makes it possible, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Export your iCal to Google Mail.  It has a daily agenda feature.

Comment: It's much more helpful if you explain *how* in your answer.  Remember, our audience has a broad range of skill levels.